# How is the cross product an orientation dependend pseudo-vector, since the right hand rule uniquely determines its direction?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, differential-forms, orientation

The geometric definition of the cross product $a\times b$ of two vectors (arrows) $a$ and $b$ seems unambiguous, in particular its direction is uniquely determined by the right hand rule.

So why is the cross product called a pseudo vector (or pseudo form) whose direction depends on the orientation of the vector space? There must be a connection between the geometric definition and the formula $a\times b=*(a\wedge b)$ I found, where the dependency on the orientation is explicit, musn't it?

Comment: Using the right hand rule is choosing an orientation. A different orientation would use the left hand rule.

Comment: The Hodge star depends on a choice of orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the canonical basis $B=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, there exist two different orientations. The classical one is saying $B$ is positively oriented, the other is saying $B$ is negatively oriented.

The cross product of two linearly independant vectors $u$ and $v$ is defined to be the unique vector $w$, orthogonal to $u$ and $v$, such that $\|w\| = \|u\|\|v\||\sin(u,v)|$ and $(u,v,w)$ is a positively oriented basis. Positively oriented means that $\det_B(u,v,w) >0$ if $B$ is positively oriented, $<0$ otherwise.

The second point is where the orientation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ matters. If you chose $B$ to be positively oriented, then $e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$ (right hand rule).
If you say that $B$ is negatively oriented, then $e_1\times e_2 = -e_3$.
In general, the change of orientation induces a multiplication by $(-1)$ on the cross product.

In a general orientable riemannian manifold, a metric $g$ induces the Hodge operator $\star$, which can define similar things. It closely depend on the volume form induced by the metric $g$ and thus, on the orientation of the manifold.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much :) But this makes me wonder about another thing: If you ask a physicist why the cross the product is a pseudo vector, he'll show you [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/4j1CGQL1LSDPnj2r5) picture. That is, if I reflect $u$ and $v$ in a plane and then determine the cross product using the right hand rule, I don't get the same result I get wenn I reflect $u\times v$ (which was also determined using the right hand rule). Do you have an idea of how this is related to your explanation?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are linearly independant and if $w = u\times v$, then $-w$ satisfies the definition of the cross product of $(-u)$ and $v$. Thus, $-w = (-u)\times v$ and this shows that $-(u\times v) = (-u)\times v$.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't understand why that can be regarded as a proof that the cross product is a pseudo-vector.

Comment: Another way to see this, "with the hands", is that the cross-product is closely related to the determinant. Hence, applying a positive symmetry (a rotation) mutiplies the determinant by the determinant of the rotation, that is, $1$ and does not change the cross product, but applying a negative symmetry (a reflexion) multiplies the determinant by the determinant of a reflexion, that is $(-1)$, and thus the cross product is multiplied by $(-1)$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are saying, let me try to put this into symbols. Assume we have chosen an orientation and let $\times$ be the cross product with respect to that orientation. Let $u,v,w\in V$, then $(u,v,u\times v)$ is a positively oriented basis. If $T\colon V\to V$ is a linear transformation with determinant $-1$, then $(Tu,Tv,T(u\times v))$ is negatively oriented, thus $Tu\times Tv\neq T(u\times v)$ (the triple $(Tu,Tv,Tu\times Tv)$ is by definition a positively oriented basis). Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes this is it.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much :) You can't overestimate how much you helped me, because I have to give a talk about electrodynamics and I need to explain why the magnetic field is a pseudo form (it has to do with the cross product).